# SQL Server stored procedure: if vairable = X, case where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I was able to craft this and it works, though I'm not sure why or if there is a cleaner way.

Basically I have an ASP.NET C# server side that's going to be passing a parameter. If the parameter = 0, I want the select to return everything

If the select is anything but zero, I want to just return the specific row.

```
DECLARE @OrgId INT = 0 


;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
        o.ID_PK OrgId, ISNULL(o.Parent_ID_FK, 1) ParentId, 
        o.Organization_Name
    FROM
        DYN_Organization o
    WHERE
        o.Is_Active = 1
        AND @OrgId LIKE CASE @OrgId
                           WHEN '0' THEN '0'
                           ELSE o.ID_PK
                        END
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
```

Again this works like I want it to, I just don't know why. I thought I would have to put `%` but it didn't like that. I was just testing my query when I realized it worked.

Comment: Is ID_PK an integer?  I get that you are converting to a string so you can use like but that is very seldom a good thing to do.

Comment: This topic and different / better approaches discussed in extensive detail in [Erland's blog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).  Using LIKE in this manner is confusing since it is logically the same as the EQUALS (=) operator. Typically one sees this written as "where o.ID_PK = _OrgId or _OrgId is null" (because most use NULL as the "all" option rather than a specific flag value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could emulate this behavior with the logical `or` operator, or better yet, with `in` which is a shorthand over a series of `or`ed equal checks:

```
;WITH cte AS
(

    SELECCT o.ID_PK OrgId, ISNULL(o.Parent_ID_FK, 1) ParentId, o.Organization_Name
    FROM    DYN_Organization o
    WHERE   o.Is_Active = 1 AND
            @OrgId IN ('0', o.ID_PK)

)
SELECT * FROM cte
```